# Code to extract text fields from a mongodb collection and append it to a list in python using pymongo

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have created an if statement to cycle through a mongodb collection of json objects and extract the text field from each and append it to a list. Here is the code below.

```
appleSentimentText = []
   for record in db.Apple.find():
     if record.get('text'):
       appleSentimentText.append(record.get("text"))
```

This works grand but I have 20 collections to do this to and I fear the code may start to get a little messy and unmanageable with another 19 variations of this code. I have started to write a piece of code that may accomplish this. Firstly I have created an array with the names of the 20 collections in it shown below.

```
filterKeywords = ['IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Apple','Google', 'Amazon', 'EBay', 'Diageo',
              'General Motors', 'General Electric', 'Telefonica', 'Rolls Royce', 'Walmart', 'HSBC', 'BP',
              'Investec', 'WWE', 'Time Warner', 'Santander Group']
```

I then use this array in an if statement to cycle through each collection

```
for word in filterKeywords:
  for record in db[word].find():
    if db[word].get('text'):
```

I now want it to create a list variable based on the collection name (ie AppleSentimentText if collection is apple, FacebookSentimentText if it is Facebook collection, etc) though im unsure of what to do next. Any help is welcome

Comment: Why do you need to create a variable per collection?

Comment: I need to create a variable per collection as I want to perform sentiment analysis on the text in each collection separately.

Comment: I got it but instead why not use a single list variable and clear the contain when you are done before moving to the next collection. Because If what you want is create a variable dynamically it is probably not a good idea

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Why would not be a good idea? As I said I'm quite new to all this so do bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#limit-fields-to-return-from-a-query) the returned field to **"text"** so it doesn't need to go through all records, in **pymongo** it should be something like this:

#### Edited:

As @BarnieHackett pointed out, you can filter out the `_id` as well.

```
for word in filterKeywords:
    for r in db[word].find({'text': {'$exists': True}}, {'text': 1, '_id': False}):
        appleSentimentText.append(r['text'])
```

The key is to use `$exists` and then limit the return field to `'text'`, unfortunately since **pymongo** returns the cursor which includes the `'_id'` & `'text'` field, you need to filter this out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can filter out _id as well: for r in db[word].find({'text': {'$exists': True}}, {'text': True, '_id': False}):

Comment: @BernieHackett, thanks for the pointer, I have edited the answer accordingly :)